Fail fast is brittle
I am creating a CSV consumer (with Java). There is one field / column that should contain one of the values "Rename" or "Move".
I implemented this by allowing mixed case of letters, and blank space at either end. To be precise I used myString.trim().toUpperCase()  on the parsed string.
This makes my code less brittle and more robust, but seems to ignore the "fail fast" strategy.
Should I leave the code as it is, or avoid .trim().toUpperCase()?

You're using the words "fail fast" and "brittle" in a way that may not be immediately obvious. Your question doesn't show how your goals might be in conflict. That small fragment of code looks perfectly fine so far.

People using case and whitespace variants with obvious meanings is not a "condition that is likely to indicate a failure", hence any advice that "fail fast" might imply does not apply.

Is there an agreed-upon format for the csv? If it is agreed that the values will have the specific case, then it would be appropriate to fail on case-mismatch, since it might indicate a bug which you need to investigate. E.g. hypothetically "Move" and "MOVE" could be different instructions.

@JacquesB thats the exact opposite of the highest voted answer

@NimChimpsky: The currently highest voted answer is bad advice. Postels Law is generally regarded as a mistake and have been denounced by the IETF. See https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-iab-protocol-maintenance-05.html Quote: "Time and experience shows that negative consequences to interoperability accumulate over time if implementations apply the robustness principle.

@JacquesB what is the ietf ?

@JacquesB: if you don't like aspects of my answer, please tell me directly. I accept your critics to some degree and changed the wording, hope it is clearer now.

The question focusses on fail-fast which makes sense if you see this problem from the context of one part: Processing the CSV. But actually it seems your software has multiple parts: Load CSV, Validate CSV, Parse CSV, store end result. Maybe you even need TranslateCSV in between. For the Parse piece a fail fast might be right. But for steps before that it might be reasonable to "fix" the CSV if that is your business case. Then the Parse stays clean (only standard CSV format) but the transformers before can modify the CSV. This gives every piece a Single Responsibility which is more clear.

@LucFranken the most important part here is actually the definition of the format (CreateCSV in a sense). Everything else is derived from it.

Duplicate of Be liberal in what you accept... or not?. Beware invalid top answer.

Whether this is considered 'failing fast' depends on your system boundaries.  If both the producer and consumer of this CSV are considered part of a single system, you could talk about this as 'failing fast'.  But each are considered separate systems, it's better to think about this as a requirement question and specify the chosen behavior as part of the contract specification.

If the values in the CSV does not exactly conform to the agreed-upon format, then you should fail fast and investigate the issue. It might be an error in the specification or a bug in the software on either end, but in any case you want to investigate it immediately. You do not want to process illegal data and potentially gloss over bugs or data corruption.
There are plenty of cases where the meaning of words may differ due to case - the classic example is "Turkey" (a country) and "turkey" (a large bird). In your particular case with just two values it might seem reasonably safe, but it is still an unnecessary risk which provide no benefit, and as a general rule it is a very bad idea.
There might also be other systems which process the same CSV file but treat case-discrepancies different, leading to inconsistent transactions. You absolutely want to investigate such issues immediately rather than sweep them under the rug.
Of course, if it is specifically agreed that the format is case-insensitive then converting to upper case is fine, but this would not be a question of robustness, just of following the spec. (Although case insensitivity is a can of worms if you go outside the ASCII character range, so it is not necessarily a good default.)
The question of white-space is pretty cut-and-dried. The RFC for CSV states that "Spaces are considered part of a field and should not be ignored." So unless you have specifically agreed with the producer of the CSV that whitespace should be ignored, you should not trim fields.
If you have to do with end-user input (e.g. someone typing into a search box) it might be a good idea to trim, perform case-insensitive matching, ignore diacritical, accepts a certain degree of misspellings etc. But this is a completely different scenario than machine-to-machine communication like a CSV.

Please add more on protocol maintenance and versioning. Those comments are gold.

I agree to all of what you wrote, except one thing: the assumption that CSV is always a machine-to-machine format on which everyone who uses it should apply that RFC. Often enough, people often use spreadsheets like Excel to produce such data, and one should investigate clearly where the CSV comes from before jumping to conclusions.

@DocBrown people are capable to interpret good error messages. So the problem you describe can/should be handled by a validation application/macro.

In the real world, things are not always cut and dry.  I agree that things should be a tight as possible, but many times clients send less than ideal data and they are not willing to change it.   One can default to a strict adherence to start with but build in exceptions/cleansing as needed.  For example, client A may be strict, but client B may need trimming of whitespace.  So, you can add in those directives over time via a processing configuration by client.  These additional directives tell you parser about how to handle each field.

@JonRaynor there is no need to relax a protocol in the scenario you describe. Instead, create two strict protocols, one for client A and one for client B.

@Basilevs - I was thinking one CSV protocol parsing/protocol, and then after CSV has been parsed having post processing that is client specific like trimming, upper casing, etc. on fields as described by a client configuration.  That way you could always log what was originally parsed and then log the transformation that would be client specific.  This also separates CSV protocol errors versus post processing errors.  If a client is following CSV correct, there would be no need for further post processing (ideal case).

@JonRaynor, that's implementation details, not really relevant to discussion. However, I notice that you use operations, that take a wide space of inpults and accept them all, shrinking the space. This is unacceptable, as you would not be able report redundant spaces, invalid cases, etc. Instead your adapter layer could transform one valid format to another vlaid format without losing information. Example: MOVE=> Move, Move, mOve=> error

In this case, we accept two, distinct formats Move and MOVE, but never mix them and report any inconsistencies.

It just depends. Is the program we're talking about ingesting data from a source over which we have no control where we know that sometimes a column is capitalized and sometimes not? If so, I want my program to be capable to not be strictly case sensitive on the way in but I do want it to be on the way out.

@DeanMacGregor It is very risky to make guesses if the data input does not conform to the agreed specification. Imagine for example a money transfer request is sent to two banks from an ATM. The message key is corrupted because of a bug or glitch. The one bank reject the transfer because it doesn't conform to the specification. But your bank accept the message despite it being malformed. Who is to blame is funds disappear?

@JacquesB The question is about a CSV consumer not an interbank communication protocol. I scrape a lot of CSV data and literally 0 of it comes from a source that is going to mutually agree with me to a rigid specification. The best I can ever hope for is that it stays relatively consistent over time. That said, I recognize that not everyone has the same experience and might be ingesting CSV files where there's a mutually agreed specification which is why I prefaced my comment with "It just depends".

@DeanMacGregor The bank transfer was just an example to show the potential problems with processing non-conformant data. Your CSV might not be as critical as financial transactions, but presumably the data matters to someone who would prefer to avoid data loss or corruption. But in the case there isn't a specification at all (and you can't directly speak with the producer of the data to agree on a spec), then you will have to reverse-engineer the data format by investigating the messages.

Fail fast means you fail at the earliest time you spot a mistake, so you can go and check what is wrong, and not work with wrong data until it is really bad.
In this case, what was the definition of the data? Was it defined that it can be only "Move" or "Rename"? If so, then fail on "MOVE" or "rename" and take the failure and go to your data source and ask them.
Maybe the data is wrong, then it is good you caught it early. Before they send over 5000 files or before you process the data in the other fields, that may have the wrong capitalization, too.
Maybe the definition is wrong and it should have read

"move" or "rename" in any capitalization

Then fix it in the definition.
Either way, right now, when you fail fast, it is an easy fix. Either the producer produces one new file or you ammend the definition slightly. No harm done. Don't wait to ask this question until numerous files have already been processed. That is the beauty of "fail fast".

Exactly. Allowing mixed case and white space in the data is fine - if you need to. "Fail fast" just means "detect format errors as early as possible", not "mess with your input data rules to make this easy".

For situations where some data constellation indicates a bug in code, "fail fast" is usually the only viable a strategy - the program shall be stopped, and the programmer or vendor needs to fix the bug. For processing input data from an external source, "failing fast" can be a viable strategy, too, but here it can also be viable to make the process failure-tolerant to some degree. It not always sensible to be as strict about such input data as about one's own code.
So the important two questions you need to ask here are:
Where does the csv file come from? and,
How strictly / formal is the spec for the csv about the attribute in stake?

In case it comes from an external source not under my direct control, I would not stop processing when a column's content doesn't 100% conform to a spec, but can still be identified reliably. It may be debatable if it is a good idea to apply Postel's law, but at least for data which may have been entered by a human, or in cases where specs leave some room for interpretation, it can be best to be somewhat liberal in regards to extra spaces and upper/lower case.

In case the csv is output of another component under my direct control and part of the same program I am currently writing, and wrong letters or additional spaces are indicators for potential error in that component, I would consider "fail fast" instead and stop processing immediately. Same holds when when the spec for the CSV file is strictly excluding other spellings and extra spaces.


One could also try to log any variance against a spec, but that will only make sense when there is a chance the "external source" (for example, the maintainers of an external component producing that csv file) will ever get the logging results.
In the end, it is a case-specific question, a trade-off between

how much costs will it cause to accept potentially wrong data, vs.

how much costs will it cause to refuse some most probably right data?



https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-iab-protocol-maintenance-05.html

Unfortunately, we can't relax validation rules in public interface, so we have to reject even small discrepancies. The reason is simple - relaxed requirements is a feature(even if it is not documented), users rely on features. Removal of such feature is backward incompatible. Making irreversible changes like that should be done only when all other options are exhausted. Initial version of your program HAS TO contain the strictest validation possible, relax it only after user feedback and careful consideration.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9413

Honestly I first read that fail fast is for handling bugs. AFAIK is general principle that is better to detect problem quickly to avoid costly handling it later -- it applies to introducing products to the market, and handling data. Avoiding bugs -- yes, because FF helps in keeping code smaller (smaller codebase = less bugs), but assuming you have bugs... I don't see direct connection.

@greenoldman in this context FF protects you from specification "bugs". If specification is ill-defined, parser failures will help discovering this.

@greenoldman: "Honestly I first read that fail fast is for handling bugs" - yes, that's what I wrote. Not sure what you are trying to tell me.

@Basilevs in this context of course this is understandable, but Doc Brown explicitly wrote "in code". Code means implementation.

@DocBrown, I simply expressed my surprise, this is the first time I saw someone ties bugs in code (i.e. handling them) with fail fast. If you could expand it a little, or give some reference it would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

@greenoldman: ok, I reworded my answer a little bit, maybe it is clearer now. Just search this site about "Fail fast", you will surely find lots of Q&As which associate this principle with bugs in code.

@DocBrown thank you for clarification. With such perspective I have no questions/doubts :-).

This is a data normalization problem.
I know, it's tempting to just throw myString.trim().toUpperCase() in wherever it's needed. It's a quick and simple change. But once it's made, it's impossible to unmake it. So don't do it unless you are rock solid sure.
Rather, make this a separate step. Something that has to be done to the data before your program gets to it. That way it's still possible to use the data and your program. But your expectations are clear.
I know, it means you have to actually decide if uppercase is going to be your standard rather than just accepting whatever. But if you've ever been in a codebase that has a mix of tabs and spaces together then you know how awful it is when no one sets a standard.
Please, stop doing this to us. It hurts.

TL;DR
Relax specification last!
Initial specification and reference implementation should be as strict as possible (there should be only one way to convey a given dataset). Permissive specification would hinder your format after a few years
Initial specification
The fact that you are asking this question indicates, that there is no well-defined specification for the file format and you are likely writing the reference implementation.
It is very important for initial specification and reference implementation to be as restrictive as possible, because relaxing the requirements is irreversible. Permissive parser would allow alternative interpretations for the specification, splitting the community and making it hard to introduce changes (extensible specification is fine, permissive is not).
While a permissive specification may help a private project and would be very convenient in a startup, it will not last.
Applicability
There are plenty of horror stories about JSON and HTML which prove this point, but those are large and and widely used. My personal experience confirms, that the same principle applies to medium-sized projects due to versioning and backward compatibility problems. Do not rest easy, thinking that your smallish web-site or desktop application are not affected!
Recommendations
Validate
If the format to parse is error-prone or inconvenient to use, before trying to relax the requirements, consider adding a good error reporting and provide a validation tool. It is trivial to produce a CSV for however strict requirements, as long as bugs are easily detected and reproduced.
Warn before relaxing
When your format is eventually adopted (either by a wide audience, or multiple product versions or multiple products) you may find incompatibilities in the ecosystem. Do not relax the specification! First, add a warning system in your reference implementation, that accepts invalid input, but reports an error. Be careful when implementing it, make sure that relaxed implementation does not interpret valid input differently.
Extensible is not permissive
Do not attempt to make the protocol extensible by relying on permissive parser. Provide strict rules for extensions. Plan for extensions from the start. Remember YAGNI - if you really think that no extensions are needed, it is fine to leave protocol fixed.
CSV is extensible if header line is required and column names are well-defined.
Versioning
Consider a versioning scheme for your data.  Versioning is paramount to remove or change a column. Sometimes a well-defined file extension is all it takes. A defined file extension is useful even without versioning, as it further restricts your initial specification (which is a good thing).
Permissive protocol is a final resort
There is nothing bad with a permissive protocol that is:

provably unavoidable
carefully considered

Once the reference implementation is stabilized and receives user feedback, the extension can be carefully considered and more inputs can be considered valid.

Yes, you are right. Lets consider some malformed csv though:
one, two, three, Move, five //correct csv pass - should pass
one, two, three, Move five //missing comma fail - should fail
one, two, three, mo     ve //missing comma and split value fail (extra space in middle not trimmed)- should fail

I'm really having to struggle to find cases where trim().toUpper() would cause a pass when you would want a fail.
You would have to introduce some extra critera, such as Move being different from mOve for this case of not failing fast to actually cause an issue.
But if we imagine the more general case you have introduced extra logic which is not part of the requirements and this is always introducing a risk of edge case errors.
In fact I have a good(?) real life example
We have a linter that checks for some best practice in our code base, its been internally designed to check for the version of .net being used. I had a project where I had put net8 as a target framework. This is technically incorrect, I should use net8.0 but vs2022 doesn't care and it works. However the internal linter tool fails as its been programmed to match the spec exactly.
If vs2022 had "failed fast" on my incorrect value I wouldn't have been left with a weird "what the hell is going wrong here, everything looks right" bug to fix.
If you change the first step in your process to accept a value outside of the spec, then you could introduce similar issues on downstream components which look back at the source csv for some reason.

Note that your first example also fails without the trim(). Only the line one,two,three,Move,five would match the specification.

I just used the common, space after a comma for visibility in the example.

“Fail fast” is better than “hide failures until the worst possible time” but best is “don’t fail”.
But please decide: If you expect “whatever”, is “   WHATevER   “ an acceptable input to you? If yes, use trim + toUpperString and compare to “WHATEVER” and avoid an incorrect failure. If you think that only “whatever” is acceptable then check for this. (In that case, trim + toUpperString would be daft if you spend extra work in order to not fail fast, why would you do that? No check at all would be avoiding “fail fast”).

I suggest you look into regular expressions. This can help you create a likely cleaner and more flexible solution that still performs quite well.
Failing fast is meaningless if the fail case is rare, like with an improperly formatted input. Then there is no gain in failing fast.
Fail fast in my mind applies to the way you approach a complex problem. You identify the hard parts and focus on those first. If you fail to tackle those, you lost the minimum amount of time. If you succeed, the rest will be smooth sailing.

@IvovanderVeeken Failing fast can be more efficient. Like early exit. The alternative is to follow a fixed order of steps regardless, perhaps producing results that may need to be discarded later. The latter could be cleaner. If the fail is rare one might prefer the clean approach. Like exceptions (as an error handling mechanism) are expensive but you don't care because they are, well, exceptional.

Why is the comment I responded to deleted? I found my own comment from a couple of days earlier deleted too. Is SESE playing YouTube these days? It smells like AI and it better end soon.
